# SSRS Url Access Specify Format Breaks Report When Parameter Page is Triggered

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS (2008R2) Url Access to render reports in a web application.  I need to specify the format of the report, and am able to successfully do so using the `rs:Format=` option, so long as the report doesn't have any required parameters that need to be specified.

If the report requires the user to enter a parameter, it fails.  If I then remove the `rs:Format` option from the URL, the report's parameter page will come up fine and if I make selections, the report will render.

**My URL Access URL looks like this:**
https://www.imnottelling.com/ReportServer_SQL2008R2/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/AppReports/Cool+Report&rs:Command=Render&rc:LinkTarget=main

Note that the error message I receive when attempting this tells me that a parameter is missing, which varies, depending on the report that is attempted to run.

This leads me to believe that either (A) this is not supported or (B) I'm missing something in my URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be 'as designed' I believe as the 'rs:' portion of the url is saying 'RenderState(something)'.  If the report has REQUIRED parameters you have three choices:

1. Set a default
2. Pass them to the Rest URI
3. Remove them if you want to autogenerate via Rest URI

Generally you just need to add the parameters to your rest uri like:

main root

```
http:// (servername)/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?
```

directory (if you have one)

```
%2fTest%2f
```

itemname:

```
ComboWithParm
```

renderit:

```
&rs:Command=Render
```

parameters:

```
&Parm=HereIAmPassedInThroughAnUrl
```

All at once:

```
http:// (servername)/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTest%2fComboWithParm&rs:Command=Render&Parm=HereIAm
```

If you are using a web application with .NET technologies and ASP.NET I believe you can use the report viewer object.  Else you may be forced to deal with using the report url.  I know I read a book by Brian Larson for SSRS 2008 and he had an example where you basically bind an HTML form and also use a select node in the form object to set properties of the service.  If you were doing HTML natively this may be a good idea as well.  It was similar to this:

```
<form id="frmRender" action="http:// (servername)/(pathtoreport)" method="post" 
 target="_self">
<H3>My Report Title</H3>
Render in the following format:<br/>
<Select ID="rs:Format" Name="rs.Format" size=1>
<Option Value="HTML4.0">HTML 4.0</Option>
<Option Value="IMAGE">TIFF IMAGE</Option>
</Select>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you set the default render format in SSRS for a report?  You mentioned this as an option but I haven't seen where to set it.

Comment: Not in the url but you can do whatever you want in a form that a user sees.  The beauty of the service is you don't have to present it to an end user.  I meant you can set defaults on parameters.  The default method if you specify nothing is the web view I believe of SSRS.

Comment: Got it.  I was trying to avoid building a custom parameters page, but it looks like that's the only way to do it.  Thanks!